# Java - Processing file with three threads

Tags: java, spring, file, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

```
ExecutorService executor1 = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        ExecutorService executor2 = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        ExecutorService executor3 = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        ArrayBlockingQueue<String> abq = new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(1000);
        try {

             String line;
             InputStream is = file.getInputStream();
             br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
             while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                 String[] values = line.split(",");
                 List<String> valuesList = Arrays.asList(values);
                 for(String valueList : valuesList) {
                     abq.put(valueList);
                     executor2.execute(new Runnable () {
                         public void run() {
                             System.out.println(valueList + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                         }
                     });
```

Hi
I am trying to do the following:

1. Read file from main thread
2. Store the read value to a blockingqueue, from which another thread will access and process.
3. Have another thread to write to another file.
   But I am confused as to how to do this.
   If I declare a fixedthreadpool, I wont have control on which thread does what, but in this approach isnt this similar to sequential processing as the thread belong to different pools?
   If someone can guide me how to do this, it will help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand what you want to do, but I'd do it like this:
I create 3 Threads and name them differently, based on the name I make them run 3 different methods:
the first one that reads the file and puts the result in an arraylist shared by all trheads and static
the second has an infinite loop (or a task that runs every certain time if you want to do some optimization) which always takes the first element of the arraylist and processes it and puts it in another arraylist which is also shared and static
the third thread also has a loop (or task) which always takes the first element and prints it to file.

I would do so but maybe I didn't understand, if you need to write me

(google translator from: Italian to: English)

Comment: Yes that is what I am doing right now, but if threads are from different pool, won't they execute sequentially?

Comment: mhm, you can't just do a class
ThreadOperation extends Thread

with a main method that sets the name and with 3 methods (the ones I wrote about)

then you create them in the main method or wherever you like

and you start them with higher priority than the one that reads the files.

(shared arrays you should put them in the class where you create the threads (not the class you extend to thread)

Answer (score 0):

We are performing these 2 tasks:

1. Read + Deserialize input (read bytes from file and parse into Java object "message")
2. Serialize + Write output (transform to target format and write)

Please note that the approach to use 2 different threads working sequentially with synchronized (blocking) message handover is probably only needed when looking at *some particular high-throughput scenarios*. The work associated with each task for each thread must normally be *balanced* (i.e. take a similar amount of CPU cycles) for this to even be beneficial. Or, that output is written to e.g. cloud storage or something that may intermittently stall.

You're correct in that you must use a thread-safe queue for handover between threads! The easiest approach is to instantiate and set up the interactions between the 2 threads directly (instead of using ExecutorService).

For a code example, please see below. Here we assume the Java objects representing the messages are called `MyMsg` and that the serialized form is `String`-based in both input and output files:

```
public class ProcessorExample {

  private static final MyMsg END = new MyMsg(); // used to signal file read finished

  public void processFile(File inFile, File outFile) {
    BlockingQueue<MyMsg> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(4096);
    Thread reader = new Thread(() -> read(queue, inFile), "reader");
    Thread writer = new Thread(() -> write(queue, outFile), "writer");
    reader.start();
    writer.start();
  }

  private void read(BlockingQueue<MyMsg> queue, File inFile) {
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFile))) {
      String line;
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        queue.put(deserialize(line)); //surround with try/catch to drop failed messages
      }
      queue.put(END);
    } catch (IOException|InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO: Graceful handling of exceptions at file level
    }
  }

  private void write(BlockingQueue<MyMsg> queue, File outFile) {
    try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outFile))) {
      MyMsg msg;
      while ((msg = queue.take()) != END) {
        writer.write(serialize(msg)); //surround with try/catch to drop failed messages
      }
    } catch (IOException|InterruptedException e) {
      // TODO: Graceful handling of exceptions at file level
    }
  }

  private MyMsg deserialize(String str) {
    return null; //TODO implement
  }

  private String serialize(MyMsg msg) {
    return null; //TODO implement
  }

}
```

Some final thoughts:

- For the highest throughput, consider using lock-free Single-Producer Single-Consumer queues from [JCTools](https://github.com/JCTools/JCTools) instead of `ArrayBlockingQueue`
- Test your code on your actual workloads whenever possible to get real performance numbers applicable for your use-case.
- If you are going to process a huge number of files (>10k), it might be good to start reusing threads.
- If this is in fact not a "high-throughput" scenario but really an issue with slow deserialization/serialization, then I'd suggest to first look at how to improve those methods. There are great algos and libs out there to perform stuff that may otherwise take a very long time (reading huge XMLs, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I see various solutions being posted, but I'm questioning if you want to split the reading and writing to a file at all.

If you are going to process many files in parallel, then I would start with reading and writing on a single thread sequentially so that no synchronization is needed and hence you are not wasting the potential of the CPU.

And you can process multiple files in parallel by having multiple threads.

I would start with creating some benchmarks e.g. using JMH and see what the bottleneck actually is before jumping into a multi-threaded solution. A single CPU can do a huge amount of work if properly used.

If you are using Linux, then for simple sequential I/O you don't need to wait for disk access (so it isn't synchronized I/O). Linux relies on a feature called read ahead, which prefetches the data, your process is going to read, into the page cache. In case of sequential reads, the prefetch window will be maximized. So when your local read buffer is drained, it just needs to look into the page cache for the next data to load in the user-space buffer because the read-ahead probably already has loaded the data into the page cache. And with buffered I/O the writes also first end up in the user-space buffer; once the buffer fills up, it is written to the page cache. Only at some point in the future, the dirty pages will be written to disk. And modern NVMe SSD's have insane speeds (multiple gigabytes per second) for sequential reads/writes.